# Image reading in PHP displays code rather than image

Tags: php, fopen

I have the following code that reads image.jpg from a folder, but despite adding the (assumed) correct header AND checking correct MIME is set on IIS, it displays code rather than showing the image.

```
<?php
// open the file in a binary mode
$name = 'image.jpg';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
?>
```

Displays code :

����JFIFHH��C��C����"��

Comment: Why not just use `<img src="<?php echo $name; ?>" />` ?

Comment: @DaveyBoy Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either, it just displays code rather than the image.

Comment: When you say "displays code", what do you actually mean? Do you mean that `echo $name` is displayed in the image's place or something else?

Comment: @DaveyBoy it displays 'garbage' similar to indicated in the original question, rather than the image, it just displays random characters like this: ����JFIFHH��C��C����"��

Comment: OK. Rather than *all* of your shown code, you should just be using the `<img src="<?php echo $name; ?>" />`  structure. The data that is being displayed is the header information from a JPEG file. Have you opened the JPEG file in another program (GIMP?) to check that it is valid? Have you tried a variety of browsers? Have you tried hard coding the image name in the `<img.../>` tag to check that it works correctly?